# Array bank system: issue with transferring a value

Tags: java, arrays, system, bank

I'm in a beginner's Java class. I am trying to implement a method that transfers a value to another account. I can't figure out how to do this. As of yet, my code is as follows:

Conta.java:

```
package br.com.banco;

class Conta {
    private int numeroConta;
    private String nome;
    private double saldo;
    private static int numeroDeContas = 0;

    // getters and setters
    public int getNumeroConta() {
        return numeroConta;
    }

    public void setNumeroConta(int numeroConta) {
        this.numeroConta = numeroConta;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public String informacaoConta() {
        return "Número da conta: " + numeroConta + "\nNome do Cliente: "
                + nome + "\nSaldo:" + saldo + "\n";
    }

    public Conta(String abc, double xyz) {
        nome = abc;
        saldo = xyz;
        numeroDeContas++;
        numeroConta = numeroDeContas;
    }

    public void deposito(double valor) {
        if (valor <= 0) {
            System.out.println("O valor precisa ser positivo");
        } else {
            saldo = saldo + valor;
        }
    }

    public void retirar(double valor) {
        if (valor <= 0) {
            System.out.println("O valor precisa ser positivo");
        } else {
            if (saldo < valor) {
                System.out.println("Valor insuficiente");
            } else {
                saldo = saldo - valor;
            }
        }
    }

    public void transfere() {
        // I need help with this
    }
}
```

Banco.java:

```
package br.com.banco;

class Banco {
    private Conta[] contas;
    private int numContas;

    public Banco() {
        contas = new Conta[100];
        numContas = 0;
    }

    public int abrirConta(String nome, double saldoInicial) {
        Conta c = new Conta(nome, saldoInicial);
        contas[numContas] = c;
        numContas++;
        return c.getNumeroConta();
    }

    public void retirarDe(int numeroConta, double valor) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numContas; i++) {
            if (numeroConta == contas[i].getNumeroConta()) {
                contas[i].retirar(valor);
                System.out.println("Valor retirado com sucesso");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Número de conta inválido.");
    }

    public void depositaEm(int numeroConta, double valor) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numContas; i++) {
            if (numeroConta == contas[i].getNumeroConta()) {
                contas[i].deposito(valor);
                System.out.println("Valor retirado com sucesso");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Número de conta inválido.");
    }

    public void Transferir() {
        System.out.println("Número de conta inválido.");
    }

    public void mostrarInformacaoConta(int numeroConta) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numContas; i++) {
            if (numeroConta == contas[i].getNumeroConta()) {
                System.out.println(contas[i].informacaoConta());
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Número de conta inválido.");
    }
}
```

Sistema.java:

```
package br.com.banco;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sistema {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Banco meuBanco = new Banco();
        int opcao;
        do {
            // display menu to user
            // ask user for their choice and validate it (make sure it is between 1 and 6)
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1) Abrir uma nova conta");
            System.out.println("2) Depositar");
            System.out.println("3) Sacar");
            System.out.println("4) Transferir");
            System.out.println("5) Saldo");
            System.out.println("6) Sair");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Escolha uma opção [1-6]: ");
            opcao = s.nextInt();
            switch (opcao) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Digite seu nome");
                    String cn = s.next();
                    System.out.println("Digite o saldo inicial da conta");
                    double d = s.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Conta criada com sucesso, o número da conta é: " + meuBanco.abrirConta(cn, d));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Digite o número da conta");
                    int an = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Digite um valor para depositar");
                    double da = s.nextDouble();
                    meuBanco.depositaEm(an, da);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Digite o número da conta");
                    int acn = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Digite um valor para sacar");
                    double wa = s.nextDouble();
                    meuBanco.retirarDe(acn, wa);
                    break;
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Digite o número da conta");
                    int anum = s.nextInt();
                    meuBanco.mostrarInformacaoConta(anum);
                    break;
                // case 5: ... break;
            }
        }
        while (opcao != '6');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? Is there an usage example somewhere? Have you tried something like adding an additional method for updating the balance with another amount?

Comment: May I recommend to use English words in your code sample. It will be easier to get an answer. (Anyway English is not my prefered language neither, but I always write java code in English because also all java keywords and frameworks are in the same language.)

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: I do not know how to transfer an amount from one account to another account, like an idea how to implement this method using arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write your method `transferir` in the class `Banco` so it makes use of the methods `retirarDe` and `depositaEm`. After all, a transfer is really just a withdrawal from one account and a deposit of the same amount into a different account.

This way you won't even need a class `transfere` in your class `Conta`. You will, however, have to rewrite the methods `retire` in class `Conta` and `retirarDe` in `Banco` so they both returns a Boolean - `true` if the balance was sufficient and the withdrawal was successful, `false` if not, for the code below to work.

Method `transferir` in class `Banco`:

```
public void transferir(int numeroContaDe, int numeroContaA, double valor)
{
    bool suficiente = RetirarDe(numeroContaDe, valor);
    if (suficiente) {
        DepositaEm(numeroContaA, valor);
    }
}
```

Rewrite your method `retirar` in class `Conta` like this:

```
public bool retirar(double valor)
{
    if (valor <= 0) {
        System.out.println("O valor precisa ser positivo");
    }
    else {
        if (saldo < valor) {
            System.out.println("Valor insuficiente");
        }
        else {
            saldo -= valor;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And rewrite the method `retirarDe` in `Banco` like this:

```
public bool retirarDe(int numeroConta, double valor) {
    for (int i =0; i<numContas; i++) {
        if (numeroConta == contas[i].getNumeroConta()) {
            bool suficiente = contas[i].retirar(valor);
            if (suficiente) {
                System.out.println("Valor retirado com sucesso");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Salido insuficiente");
            }
        return suficiente;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Número de conta inválido.");
}
```